# Access denied for user ... when connecting from the command line

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I can't connect to mysql via command line:

```
$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

$ mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'alex'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

you must enter your password too like this:

```
mysql -u Username -pPassword
sample (Suppose that username is root and password is 123):
mysql -u root -p123
```

Answer (score -1):

If you get an Access denied error when trying to connect to the database with mysql -u user_name, you may have a problem with the user table. Check this by executing mysql -u root mysql and issuing this SQL statement:

SELECT * FROM user;

The result should include a row with the Host and User columns matching your client's host name and your MySQL user name.

[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-connecting.html)

Also try running the command as root as some user accounts will not automatically have access.